# copy numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a Nx3 array A, and another empty MxNx3 array B. I want to copy the values from A to B such that those sets of values appear M times in B. How to do this efficiently other than using a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `b[:] = a` and let broadcasting take over. For example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> b = np.zeros((3, 2, 3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> b
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Then to copy `a` into `b`:

```
>>> b[:] = a
>>> b
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.]],
       [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.]],
       [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.]]])
```

Note that `b` has to be able to hold the datatype of `a`. If `a` was an array of complex numbers, the imaginary part would be lost when copying to `b` (because it can only hold float values).

Comment: TIL broadcasting works for slice assignment instead of just on mathematical operators

Answer (score 2):

You also could write: suppose your array `a` is *numpy array*

```
    ans = numpy.array([a.tolist()*M])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for large arrays [`numpy.repeat(a, repeats, axis)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is the fastest option, despite allocating `b`'s memory on the fly.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20 * 30 * 40).reshape(20, 30, 40)
b = np.empty((16, 20, 30, 40))

%timeit b[:] = a
# 272 µs ± 22.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.empty((16, 20, 30, 40))[:] = a
# 277 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, ...], repeats=16, axis=0)
# 140 µs ± 483 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```